# Cross validation on clinical datasets

Tags: cross-validation, regression-strategies

I am very new to R programming. In my project I need to perform a Cross validation for the clinical datasets (small). I want to know what will be the results. I am unable to recognize the results.
I will be more pleased, If any one provide me a cross validations like LOOCV, K-fold. if possible with example. And please highlight the results.
Thank you all for your time.
Looking forward to hear from you people.

Answer (score 1):

Among many other options, see the R `rms` package's `validate` and `calibrate` functions.  Be absolutely certain that you repeat all screening and modeling steps when doing bootstrapping or cross-validation.  For example, it is completely *inappropriate* to select "significant" predictors and then to do re-sampling validation without re-selecting the "significant" variables for each re-sample.